# PhpAmqpLib Broken pipe or closed connection during index reindex

Tags: magento2, reindex, cli, index

I ran this command below in my Adobe Commerce Cloud 2.4.6 to reindex it.

```
MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=$(nproc) php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento i:reindex
```

Then I got these error messages that suddenly appeared:

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Attributes Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:171
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(157): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php(103): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(595): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(651): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame()
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(235): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(352): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame()    
#6 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait()
#7 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#8 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#10 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 171
process error during indexation process:
Fail in child process
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product/Target Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Target Rule/Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
process error during indexation process:
Fail in child process
Product Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Overrides Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Sales Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
ElasticSuite Category Indexing index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
ElasticSuite Thesaurus Indexing index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(408): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write()
#1 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(536): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write()
#2 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(248): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame()
#3 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(198): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame() 
#4 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(207): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel->close()
#5 /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Config.php(119): Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->closeConnection()
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Amqp\Config->__destruct()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /app/jekmwlkwevx/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 235
```

How could I solve it? Is it related to my RabbitMQ service?

Answer (score 1):

Info:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/tools/quality-patches-tool/release-notes.html?lang=en#v1-1-37

Patch list:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/tools/commerce-quality-patches/index.html

Patch ID: ACSD-53750